# Multiple IF statements without adding them together

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula in Excel that is comprised of 6 separate formulas each with multiple criteria, I will try and explain what I am trying to do below.

If the value in B7 is 2 and the value in F7 is between 3 or 0 the value in G7 is assigned as A, if the value in B7 is 2 but the value in F7 is between 4 and 6, the value in G7 is assigned as B etc..

I have managed to get it working when the value in B7 is 1 but I cannot get it working for when the value is 1 or 2.

I have tried using the & between the two formula but all it does is add them together. I have tried using ELSEIF, IF(OR(AND as well as multiple other combinations, all to no avail. My formula for when the value in B7 is 1 is below.

=IF(AND(B7=1,F7<=1),"A",IF(AND(B7=1,F7>=2,F7<=4),"B","C"))

One example of what I have tried to get it working for 1 and 2
=IF(AND(B7=1,F7<=1),"A",IF(AND(B7=1,F7>=2,F7<=4),"B","C"))OR(IF(B7=2,F7<=3),"A",IF(AND(B7=2,F7>=4,F7<=6),"B","C"))

Thank you

Comment: Try : =IFERROR(LOOKUP(F7,CHOOSE(B7,{0,2,5},{0,4,7}),{"A","B","C"}),"")

Comment: That is perfect, thank you. Could you possibly explain how it works exactly? I have managed to make a few alterations to what you posted to get it exactly how I want but I do not fully understand how it is working.

Comment: This formula using Approx. Lookup function, try to Google "  Approx. Lookup" you will get more details of how it is working.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is a combined formula with 2 Approx. Lookup formulas for Table 1 and Table 2 as show in below picture

[image]

1] Approx. Lookup formula for Table 1 :

```
=LOOKUP(F7,{0,2,5},{"A","B","C"})
```

2] Approx. Lookup formula for Table 2 :

```
=LOOKUP(F7,{0,4,7},{"A","B","C"})
```

3] To choose Table 1 or Table 2 using CHOOSE function

```
=CHOOSE(B7,{0,2,5},{0,4,7})
```

So, the combined formulas become >>

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(F7,CHOOSE(B7,{0,2,5},{0,4,7}),{"A","B","C"}),"")
```

Finally add an error trap IFERROR function in return blank for B7 give number other than 1 or 2.